# Javascript Controlled Assessment (v.2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

So, I am making a program for my controlled assessment. I put up a post before and fixed it (kind of). Before, my script, when ran, didn't display an image at all. However now, it displays a black box with a white cross inside it. I know this suggests there is a missing image but there isn't! The links are correct and so are the images. Please help!

PS: I do not want anyone to tell me please, it is something I want to learn, I just need support! I will post my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Traffic Lights</h1>
<button onClick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
<img id="image">

<script>

var lights =[
    "./Images/trafficRed.jpeg",
    "./Images/trafficRedAmber.jpeg",
    "./Images/trafficGreen.jpeg",
    "./Images/trafficAmber.jpeg"
];

var change = document.getElementById("image");
var lightStatus = "red"

function changeLights() {
    if (lightStatus == "green") {
        lightStatus = "amber"
        change.src=lights[2];
    } else if (lightStatus == "amber") {
        lightStatus = "red"
        change.src=lights[3];        
    } else if (lightStatus == "red") {
        lightStatus = "redAmber"
        change.src=lights[0];      
    } else {
        lightStatus = "green"
        change.src=lights[1];      
    }



}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it can be because of relative paths. is it working when you put absolute paths into lights array? just replace ./ with http://www.yourdomain.tld/

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the code, apart from it being strange that the lightstatus is always ahead of the image. Tell what doesnt't work.

Comment: I use `console.log` and track variable values through the code. Such as `function changeLights() { console.log(lightStatus)`. Or `console.log(lights)`. Or `console.log(lights[0])`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, what does "red amber" mean in the context of a traffic light? (Where I live traffic lights only have three colours; the sequence is always green, amber, red, repeat.)

Comment: @nnnnnn it means that red and amber are both active, indicating 'get ready for green *now*'